# How can I pump a large lake of lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I have a quarry set up, and it has encountered a rather large pool of lava. I can collect it and use it with cells, but that would be a waste of my time. Is there a machine I can use to collect it? I have looked into the IndustrialCraft and RedPower pumps, but none of them seem to have what I'm looking for. What can I use to pump large lakes of lava?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to using the various pumps from [IndustrialCraft](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Pump_(IndustrialCraft)), [RedPower](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Pump_(RedPower)), and [BuildCraft](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Pump_(Buildcraft_3)), what I usually do in my quarries is place a water source block in one of the top layers that are mined out.

As the quarry keeps mining the water will fill the entire surface of quarry and will instantly transform any lava to obsidian, which can be mined out without problem, and when the quarry is done you can remove the water with a single bucket.

If the quarry has already mined far down and is stuck on the lava putting a source block in the center of the lava (or multiple blocks in multiple places if it's a really big lava source) will also do the trick rather fast.

Comment: But what if I want the lava? Free energy!

Comment: Then build an Ender tank and drain the Nether for every last drop =p. Or create a Mystcraft age with a single biome of lava ocean and try to drain that :)

Answer (score 3):

The [pump from Buildcraft 3](http://feed-the-beast.wikia.com/wiki/Pump_(Buildcraft)#Draining_lava) will take care of lava and output it to any tank nearby.

Comment: Can this be set up for the generic situation of setting up a quarry and ensuring that it's not stopped by lava should it encounter it, or is it only possible to fix once the lava's exposed?

Comment: I believe that it will work with the quarry, so long as you supply it with MJ.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to solve this is to drop a Buildcraft pump directly above the lava (it doesn't matter how many blocks above it, the pump will create a pipe going down into the lava). Give the pump four Redstone Engines to power it and connect piping from the pump to a tank you wish to store it in or to a Liquid Transposer from Thermal Expansion if you wish to automatically can the lava.